# Transfer Audio-File from Client to Http Server via URLConnection

Tags: java, file-transfer

i am currently working on a programming-project in my school. I need to send an audio file (MIDI format) from the Client successfully to a Http Server. I already tried to do this myself and did much research on the internet and in the Stackoverflow forum. Currently it is possible to send the file from the client to the server, but on the server side, the audio file is not playable.

The following is the client-side-code:

```
private static void sendPOST() throws IOException{
    final int mid = 1;
    final String POST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/musiker/hörprobe?mid="+mid;
    final File uploadFile = new File("C://Users//Felix Ulbrich//Desktop//EIS Prototype MIDIs//Pop//BabyOneMoreTime.mid");
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    String CRLF = "\r\n";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    URLConnection connection = new URL(POST_URL).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    try (
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
        ){
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + uploadFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(uploadFile.getName())).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
        writer.append(CRLF).flush();
        Files.copy(uploadFile.toPath(), output);
        output.flush();
        writer.append(CRLF).flush();

        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();

        int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(responseCode);
        }
}
```

The following is the server-side-code:

```
int FILE_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE-2;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int current = 0;
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
                    String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "C://root//m"+musikerid+"hp"+(hörprobenzaehler+1)+".mid";
                    File f = new File(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    if(!f.exists()){
                        f.createNewFile();
                    }
                    InputStream input = t.getRequestBody();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = input.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    current = bytesRead;
                    do{
                        bytesRead = input.read(mybytearray, current, mybytearray.length-current);
                        if(bytesRead >= 0){
                            current += bytesRead;
                        }
                    }while(bytesRead>-1);

                    bos.write(mybytearray,0,current);
                    bos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    bos.close();
                    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                    input.close();
```

I am pretty desperate right now, because i couldn't find any solution to this problem. I need to use an HTTP server, but i don't need to use the TCP protocol (which is used right now via streams). I thought about a solution via ftp so i don't need to convert the file to a byte-array first. I assume that the problem lies exactly there. The server can't create the audio-file (midi-file) correctly from the byte-array. If anyone of you knows of a solution. Pls, i need your help :D

Greetings, Gizpo

Comment: `bos.write(mybytearray,0,current);` looks suspicious! Are you sure you want to write the entire HTTP request to your `.mid` file?

Comment: Oh well, thank you very much. So i would need to extract the midi file (byte array) itself from the input stream and write this to the file. Going to search for a solution here.

Comment: After going through my code again, i saw that i actually send only the file through the stream on the client side with: Files.copy(uploadFile.toPath(), output);    or am i wrong ?

Comment: You're sending the whole deal. When you append string to your `PrintWriter` object you are actually writing to your socket's `OutputStream`. What you need to do on the server is to read your `InputStream` line by line until you read an empty string line. Then read your midi via [read(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-).

Comment: One more thing. For reading character stream I suggest using [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) for  binary stream. Both can be constructed from `InputStream`.

Comment: If you want me to reply with an answer, post the rest of the function for the server (header, possible return value, ...) so  that I can test my solution before posting.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answers :D. If i post the whole function here, it would be too much i guess, because its an httpHandler handle() function and i have more than just the POST to handle :D. The Function itself has like 200 lines right now. But i can tell you the function header (there is no return value because its a void function). `public void handle (HttpExchange t) throws IOException{`

Comment: why don't you use Apache HttpClient instead of URLConnection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've dug deeper into the matter. I've found several problems:

- You're mixing binary and character based I/O. While you get away with it on the client side, the server has a hard time dealing with this.
- You forgot to specify the size of the file you're sending over to the server. On the server side you have no way of knowing (unless some one tells you beforehand) what the size (of the incoming file) will be.

I've edited your code and came up with this:

---

#### Client:

```
private static void sendPOST() throws IOException{
        final int mid = 1;
        final String POST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/musiker/hörprobe?mid="+mid;
        final File uploadFile = new File("C://Users//Felix Ulbrich//Desktop//EIS Prototype MIDIs//Pop//BabyOneMoreTime.mid");

        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        String CRLF = "\r\n";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        URLConnection connection = new URL(POST_URL).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        
        try (
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
        ) {
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + uploadFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Length: " + uploadFile.length()).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(uploadFile.getName())).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
            writer.append(CRLF).flush();
            Files.copy(uploadFile.toPath(), output);
            output.flush();

            int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response code: [" + responseCode + "]");
        }
    }
```

#### Server:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
    String CRLF = "\r\n";
    int fileSize = 0;
    
    String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "C://root//m"+musikerid+"hp"+(hörprobenzaehler+1)+".mid";
    File f = new File(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    
    InputStream input = t.getRequestBody();
    String nextLine = "";
    do {
        nextLine = readLine(input, CRLF);
        if (nextLine.startsWith("Content-Length:")) {
            fileSize = 
                Integer.parseInt(
                    nextLine.replaceAll(" ", "").substring(
                        "Content-Length:".length()
                    )
                );
        }
        System.out.println(nextLine);
    } while (!nextLine.equals(""));
    
    byte[] midFileByteArray = new byte[fileSize];
    int readOffset = 0;
    while (readOffset < fileSize) {
        int bytesRead = input.read(midFileByteArray, readOffset, fileSize);
        readOffset += bytesRead;
    }
    
    BufferedOutputStream bos = 
        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED));
    
    bos.write(midFileByteArray, 0, fileSize);
    bos.flush();
    
    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
}

private static String readLine(InputStream is, String lineSeparator) 
    throws IOException {

    int off = 0, i = 0;
    byte[] separator = lineSeparator.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] lineBytes = new byte[1024];
    
    while (is.available() > 0) {
        int nextByte = is.read();
        if (nextByte < -1) {
            throw new IOException(
                "Reached end of stream while reading the current line!");
        }
        
        lineBytes[i] = (byte) nextByte;
        if (lineBytes[i++] == separator[off++]) {
            if (off == separator.length) {
                return new String(
                    lineBytes, 0, i-separator.length, "UTF-8");
            }
        }
        else {
            off = 0;
        }
        
        if (i == lineBytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Maximum line length exceeded: " + i);
        }
    }
    
    throw new IOException(
        "Reached end of stream while reading the current line!");       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your code and the file gets send like it should, but again it is not playable :( . I guess it is impossible to send an audio file through streams, because for that you have to convert it into an byte [] and when you convert that array back into a file, it is not correctly converted into a sound file. Do you know a way to send the file directly, without converting it into an array ? Because i don't :(

Comment: This code works. I've only changed file names in my version. I even sent a midi file and received exactly the same, playable one. Perhaps you made a mistake while stitching my code into your solution.

Comment: And you are sending the file correctly. What does the server output after the request? I get something like this: `--1556c0471f3 \n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryFile"; filename="file.mid" \n
Content-Length: 1856 \n
Content-Type: null \n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary \n
\n
`

Comment: The server outputs this: `--1556c3a4bd8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryFile"; filename="BabyOneMoreTime.mid"
Content-Length: 53713
Content-Type: null
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` it is similar to the output of your server and yet the file is still not playable with windows media player, while the original file is playable.

Comment: i am still wondering about one thing: `FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(uploadFile); `. In my Eclipse IDE it says, that this FileInputStream on the Client Side is never used and i checked your code here again. You actually don't use it. So what do we need it for ?

Comment: You're right that line is useless. I've edited my answer with a fix. It turns out that I can only read around 8kB with one call to `read(byte[] b)` on `InputStream`. It worked for me because I was using a 2kB file. ^^

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! You are the true savior of my school project :D

Comment: While reviewing the code again I've discovered that all this trouble could have been avoided, had we used the `java.net` package correctly. All HTTP headers can be sent and received via [setRequestProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [getRequestProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getRequestProperty-java.lang.String-). That would eliminate most of the noise in the code and the actual File I/O could remain unchanged.